Values null when I make a simple post request to my .net controller from angularJS
Here is my code for AngularJS controller from which i am sending http post request to server:
function Search() {
    Filtro = new Object();
    Filtro.Usuario = $scope.UsuarioFilter;
    Filtro.Nombre = $scope.NombreFilter;
    Filtro.Rfid = $scope.RfidFilter;
    Filtro.CurrentPage = $scope.currentPage;

    GetUsuariosFilter(Filtro).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Beneficiarios = response.data; //(IsNull(response.data) ? null : JSON.parse(response.data));
    }, function (error) { alert(error.statusText); })
}

function GetUsuariosFilter(filtro) {
    return appService.POST(JSON.stringify(filtro), "/Usuarios/GetUsuariosFilter");
}

Here is my code inside C# controller:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUsuariosFilter(FiltroUsuarios Filtro)
{
    try
    {
        var response = _server.GetUsuarios();
        if (response == null) throw new Exception("Error.");
        return Json(response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new ResponseRequest() { Success = false, Message = e.Message, MessageDetail = (e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "") });
    }
}

Here is my code inside the services.js:
 this.POST = function (data, url) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     if (data == null || data == '' || data == undefined) data = '';
     var promise = $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         data: data
     }).then(function (response) {
         deferred.resolve(response);
     }).catch(function (error) {
         if (error.status == -1) {
             alert('Se produjo un error al conectar con el servidor');
         }
         deferred.reject(error);
     });
     return deferred.promise;
 }

In the AngularJS the filter is ok, but when the values go to the controller is empty all the object.

Have you tried using [FromBody] within your controller? Because, you are sending json object which needs to mactched with the model FiltroUsuarios , here model bindings got failed. You should pass the json object as data: JSON.stringify(data)

Removed [angular] tag as [angular] and [angularjs] are not the same framework.

Hi @Milagros, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern on this.

@MdFaridUddinKiron I tried the solution, It's work!!! At the moment, I have problems when I tried to send in the object into other object. For example:   public class Checklist -> public UnidadFrecuencia UnidadFrecuencia { get; set; }
When i want to send UnidadFrecuencia to the controller not recive this class

Thanks for response, if the sending model doesn't matched it won't get the value. So model bindings is crucial.


In the AngularJS the filter is ok, but when the values go to the
controller is empty all the object.

Based on your shared code, model bindings seems incorrect here. FiltroUsuarios class properties should match the structure and names of the properties being sent from AngularJS.
As I can see, you are passing application/json but controller doesn't matched with that.
So you need to fix that in order to handle the model bindings correctly by adding [FromBody] in controller and wrap the angular request with data: JSON.stringify(data)
Modify controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetUsuariosFilter([FromBody] FiltroUsuarios filtro)
{
     //Rest of your code
}

Modify Angular rquest:
this.POST = function (data, url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.status == -1) {
            alert('Se produjo un error al conectar con el servidor');
        }
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

Output:


Note: Please refer tto this official document for additional details on model binding.
